# Data Extension Exclusion List

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

Would using an exclusion list with a non-email primary key matching the non-email primary key field in the send list exclude the matching keys, or would the actual sendable email address need to be in both?

I have a data extension that has primary key as a Unique ID and the sendable Email Address is a separate non-primary field. I then have a DE that I want to use as an exclusion list, but this only has the Unique ID in it.  Would this still prevent the send on those who have a Unique ID in the exclusion list, or would the email address need to be included on this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.  You need to have the DE be sendable in order to use it as an exclusion list, so you would need to have an email address inside of the data.

On that note though, you are able to put in an exclusion script that can perform a lookup on that DE or an if statement with RaiseError if exist in DE in AMPscript inside the email.